# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I have wcf service for login user that is returning two int type values that is working fine , but the problem is when the response is sent via windows 8.1 app its throws an exception :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible
```

code :

```
         loginCS _login = new loginCS();
        _login.Email = tEmailtxt.Text;
        _login.Password = tPasstxt.Text;
        var result = await _client.UserSignInAsync(_login);
        try
        {
            GlobalClass.GlobalSchid = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            GlobalClass.GlobalUid = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage));

        }

        catch { }
```

the code :

```
GlobalClass.GlobalSchid = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

is throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the entire selection to an `int`.

Access the data inside of the collection and then cast that data, not the collection itself.

Comment: var data =result.ToArray();
                GlobalClass.GlobalSchid = data[0];
                GlobalClass.GlobalUid = data[1];

Comment: but I am getting index out of bound